# Initialize twig in constructor of class

Tags: php, twig

I am trying to initialize Twig in the constructor but I run into the issue of:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "for" tag. Did you mean "for"?`

Here is what my class looks like:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

class Test {

    public $loader;
    public $twig;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/templates');

        $this->twig = new Twig_Environment($this->loader);

        $this->show_page();
     }

     public function show_page() {
         $results = get_results_from_db();

         $template = $this->twig->loadTemplate('results.twig');

         $template->render([
             'results' => $results,
         ]);
     }
}
```

**results.twig**

```
{% for result in results %}
    <p>{{ result.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Now if I remove the loader and the twig definitions outside of the constructor and put them in the `show_page` method, it works just fine but that is not how Twig is meant to be used.

Comment: Did you define `__DIR` constant?

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev Sorry that's a typo, fixed now.

Comment: Can you try `$this->loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/templates');` instead of `$this->loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__, . '/templates');`?

Comment: I apologize again but that was also a typo, I combed through the post and now I think I got rid of all of them.

Comment: Can you try this: `$this->loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/templates'); $this->twig = new \Twig_Environment($this->loader);`?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/intro.html), you need to echo out the view when you render it. This should work fine:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

class Test
{
    public $loader;
    public $twig;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/templates');

        $this->twig = new Twig_Environment($this->loader);

        $this->show_page();
    }

     public function show_page()
     {
         $results = get_results_from_db();

        $template = $this->twig->loadTemplate('results.twig');

        echo $template->render([
            'results' => $results,
        ]);
     }
}
```